# Passing data from tableview cell to View Controller Swift 2.1

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

[image: Variable 'sendTitle' cannot access]

Anyone know why can't I access the variable 'sendTitle' in prepareForSegue from didSelectRowAtIndexPath? I saw some of the tutorials, they are doing the same thing with me, I've no idea why mine got error.
--What I'm doing now is passing value from tableView cell to another view controller.

I'm using Xcode 7 Swift 2.1

Comment: you have to declare sendTitle inside your class to make it visible to all methods

Comment: Because that is a local constants

Comment: @PK20 no, I've to assign the cell.lblTitle.text into sendTitle, how could I do this in my class?

Comment: @Leo Ya, I also knew that, but how come the others doing the same thing with me?

Comment: @jefferyleo, if you have pasted your code instead of image, I would have copied and altered it for your understanding. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to declare sendTitle inside your class to make it visible to all methods. Something like follows.

```
import UIKit

class viewController: UITableViewController {
   var sendTitle:String = ""

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
   }

   //table view delegate methods 
   // just use sendTitle = cell.lblTitle.text!

}
```

Comment: I did it like this, thank you. I think I'm confusing just now between the prepareForSegue and didSelectRowAtIndexPath. Appreciate. I will mark your answer as correct in few minutes due to the constraint of StackOverFlow

Answer (score 0):

Because it is declared privately in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method. It won't be accessible outside of those function. if you want to access it from another function, declare it as global variable in your view controller.